# bad design with goroutine called by time.AfterFunc() recursively

Tags: go

I have a small http application (A). In the startup it calls another http service (B) to verify the license and if the license is OK then http server (A) starts. If the verification fails A exits with a fatal error

The license check will happen every 24 hours

Would it be considered a bad design to create a new goroutine recursively every 24 hours. Check my code below. Will the previous goroutine close or continue running and then end up with n goroutines called by each other

Will each new goroutine be called from the main or from the child goroutine?

## License verification module. A checking service B

```
func Request(retry bool) error {
    // request and verify license (external http service)
    err := verify_license()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    if retry {
        //  Renew verification timeout (renew license every 24 hours)
        time.AfterFunc(LICENSE_TIMEOUT, func(){
            request_retry()
        })
    }
    
    return nil
}

func request_retry(){
    for i := 0; i < LICENSE_RETRY; i++ {
        if err := v.Request(false); err == nil {
            break
        }
        
        time.Sleep(LICENSE_RETRY_TIMEOUT)
    }
    
    time.Sleep(LICENSE_TIMEOUT)
    v.Request(true)
}
```

## In the main package before the HTTP server (A) starts

```
if err := license_verify.Request(true); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}
```

Comment: You wrote: _The license check will happen every 24 hours._ A [`time.Ticker`](https://pkg.go.dev/time#Ticker) is usually more appropriate for doing things at regular intervals.

Comment: @jub0bs if the license request fails I want to be able to do a few intermediate retries with a much shorter timeout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can rethink the design of the problem. For example:

```golang
func main() {
    if !checkLicense() {
        log.Fatal("license check failed")
    }

    srv := http.Server{} // 
    
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    go func() {
         for {
             select {
             case <-ctx.Done(): // in case you want to instal signal handlers etc
                  return
             case <-time.After(24 * time.Hour):
                  if !checkLicense() {
                      cancel() // or srv.Shtdown, really depends on you
                  }
             }
         }
    }()

    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func checkLicense() bool {
    // add retries per request here
}
```

Basically what it does is creates a goroutine that checks periodically and notifies the context or a channel if something goes bad.

If I understood the problem correctly, you just need to keep it simple. One building block is retry on request failure. Outside of it, is retry on 24h. Last layer is, if check fails, react on it. You can use context, channel, or anything you like really